# Fullscreen one out of two monitors in EXWM

Tags: exwm

When I am running Chromium in EXWM I can fullscreen YouTube across two monitors using YouTube's fullscreen button or F, and I can fullscreen Chromium itself across two monitors with Emacs's `C-c C-f` which runs `exwm-layout-set-fullscreen`.

Naturally there isn't much point in watching a YouTube video on one half each of two monitors. How can I tell EXWM to fullscreen something across one monitor only?

Note that the problem exists in tiling mode as well as floating mode.

Comment: If you don't get any answer here, I suggest you fill an issue on EXWM issue tracker.

Comment: Good idea. I have done so: https://github.com/ch11ng/exwm/issues/434